# WPF Mutibinding two or more binding on TextBlock Text

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, multibinding

whe I build this style xaml code, gets back this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type
>   'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a
>   DependencyObject

How I can multibinding this binding properties?
thanks in advance.

```
 <Style x:Key="TextBlockLastUnitStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Text">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} : {1}">
                <Binding Path="{Binding String57, Source={StaticResource CurrentResources}}" />
                <Binding Path="{Binding LastUnitId,FallbackValue=-.-}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>        
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bindings in a MultiBinding use XML tag syntax instead of attribute syntax:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockLastUnitStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Text">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} : {1}">
                <Binding Path="String57" Source="{StaticResource CurrentResources}"/>
                <Binding Path="LastUnitId" FallbackValue="-.-" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Great Works! I change with your suggestion, i'm forget the tag syntax, sorry

Comment: Please mark the answer as solution if it had helped you !! Thanks